# How do i get the first line of a txt file and set it as a %variable% in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to send a number to file.txt as a temporary storage for another variable, which can easily be done. I just can't work out what to use to extract the first line of file.txt (which is a number ranging 1-100000) and set it as a %variable% in my running batch script.

So by the end of it I should be able to do echo %first-line-of-file.txt% and it'll print x

Any ideas on how to make this work is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple really.

```
@echo off
For /f %%i in (file.txt) do set "var=%%i" & Goto :print
:print
Echo %var%
```

The for loop will typically loop through the entire file. But we do `goto :EOF` once the first line has been set to exit the loop.

For more help on a for loop. Open cmd.exe and type `for /?

Comment: I wish it really was that simple, but when I have any comments after the final echo there, batch tries to execute them all as well....

Comment: @Amalgovinus How are your comments constructed?

Comment: Using setlocal enabledelayedexpansion, both double-colon (and rem comments too) are getting executed as commands with their double-colon excluded. Actually this is happening even without the :print, my bad. But it's really weird. Windows 10

Comment: @Amalgovinus Does not sound right. I would need to actually see it to find what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

a `for` loop (like Gerhard showed it) is the most general approach (use `"delims="` to get the complete line, even if it contains spaces or other delimiters), but to get the *first* (or only) line of a text file, there is a simpler method:

```
<filename.txt set /p line=
echo %line%
```